# what is the usage of F_DUPFD inside fcntl in Linux system call

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am trying to understand what this line of code means:

**int dfd;**

**fd2 = fcntl(dfd, F_DUPFD);**

Answer (score 3):

It is intended to set `fd2` to another file descriptor referencing the same open-file record as `dfd`.

There should be a third argument, the lowest acceptable file descriptor to return. Since that third argument is missing, the call might do just about anything. A correct call could look like this:

```
fd2 = fcntl(dfd, F_DUPFD, 0);
```

From the [`fcntl` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl):

> `F_DUPFD` (int)
>
> Find the lowest numbered available file descriptor greater than or equal to `arg` and make it be a copy of `fd`. This is different from `dup2`(2), which uses exactly the descriptor specified.
>
> On success, the new descriptor is returned.
>
> See `dup`(2) for further details.

Comment: Yes, dup is a shortcut to fcntl generic function.